# Unable to install ffmpeg after having compiled and uninstalled it

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I have an Nvidia GPU in my computer and I wanted to use it with ffmpeg to convert video files much quicker using hardware capabilities.
On the documentation of Nvidia (ttps://developer.nvidia.com/ffmpeg), it is said that we have to recompile ffmpeg to gain support for CUDA. I am on Linux (Debian based, Ubuntu). First, I did "sudo apt remove" and then I've the repository and did :

```
sudo ./configure --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --enable-libass
sudo make -j 4
sudo make install
```

This does work pretty well with CUDA but the fact is that all the free codecs are not supported- (one example is CUDA). So I did :

```
sudo ./configure --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --enable-libass
sudo make uninstall
sudo make clean
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --pkg-config-flags="--static" --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
sudo make -j 4
sudo make install
```

The problem is, when I run the ffmpeg command, I get this error:

> maxime@maxime-X756UWK:~/ffmpeg_sources$ ffmpeg
>   bash: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

The translation is "No such file or folder of that kind".

Here's the result of the "type" commande :

> maxime@maxime-X756UWK:/usr/bin$ type ffmpeg
>   ffmpeg est haché (/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg)

The translation is "ffmpeg is hashed (/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg)"

I tried to install ffmpeg using apt, the installation worked, but I wasn't able to run the program...

Can you help me fix that issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `--bindir="$HOME/bin"` in your ffmpeg `configure`, so your `ffmpeg` executable is in `~/bin`, and not in `/usr/local/bin`. This usually isn't a problem (`~/bin` is in the default `PATH` for Ubuntu for example), but the hash table has not been updated. This is a somewhat rare case that occurs when installing, executing, uninstalling, re-installing occurs in a certain order, and is why the [FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) suggests using the `hash` command after installation.

To fix this you have several options:

- Try running `hash -d ffmpeg`.
- Or log out and log in.
- Or move `ffmpeg` from `~/bin/` to `/usr/local/bin` if you prefer that location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... after rebooting, the ffmpeg package was gone and now I'm going to recompile it using checkinstall, which is much more handy... Thank you again!